# How can I check if an input is a integer or String, etc.. in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am wondering how I can check if a user's input is a certain primitive type (I mean integer, String, etc... I think it's called primitive type?). I want a user to input something, then I check if it's a String or not, and do a certain action accordingly. (JAVA)
I have seen some codes like this:

```
if (input == (String)input) { (RANDOM STUFF HERE) }
```

or something like

```
if input.equals((String) input)
```

And they don't work. I want to know how I can **Check for only a String?** (EDITED OUT)
I was wondering if there was a function that can do that? Thanks for the answers

EDIT: With the help of everyone I have created my fixed code that does what I want it to:

```
package files;
import java.util.*;
public class CheckforSomething {
static Scanner inputofUser = new Scanner(System.in);    
static Object userInput;
static Object classofInput;
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
    System.out.print("Enter an integer, only an integer: ");
    userInput = inputofUser.nextInt();

    classofInput = userInput.getClass();
    System.out.println(classofInput);
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Not an integer, crashing down");

    }

 }



 }
```

No need for answers anymore, thanks!

Comment: What *is* `input`? *Where* did it come from, and *how*? ie. If it is a String, then it will always be a String.. and the casts make no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  **instanceof** to check type and typecast according to your type:

```
 public class A {

    public static void main(String[]s){

        show(5);
        show("hello");
    }
    public static void show(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Integer){
            System.out.println((Integer)obj);
        }else if(obj instanceof String){
            System.out.println((String)obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in that context but not with a Scanner. :(

Comment: what about if I take input from `stdio`? I need help in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this with Regex:

```
String input = "34";
if(input.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
  //okay
} else {
  // not okay !
}
```

Here,

`^\\d+` says that input starts with a digit 0-9,

`()?` may/or may not occur

`\\.` allows one period in input

Answer (score 1):

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

if (input.hasNextInt()) System.out.println("This input is of type Integer.");
else if (input.hasNextFloat()) System.out.println("This input is of type Float.");
else if (input.hasNextLine()) System.out.println("This input is of type string."); 
else if (input.hasNextDouble()) System.out.println("This input is of type Double."); 
else if (input.hasNextBoolean()) System.out.println("This input is of type Boolean.");  

  else if (input.hasNextLong())
    System.out.println("This input is of type Long.");
```

Answer (score 1):

*Hate to bring this up after 6 years but I found another possible solution.*

Currently attending a coding bootcamp and had to solve a similar problem. We introduce booleans and change their values depending on the result of the try/catch blocks. We then check the booleans using simple if statements. You can omit the prints and input your code instead. Here's what it looks like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataTypeFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        while (true) { //so we can check multiple inputs (optional)
            input = scan.nextLine();

            if ("END".equals(input)) { //a way to exit the loop
                break;
            }

            boolean isInt = true; //introduce boolean to check if input is of type Integer
            try { // surround with try/catch
                int integer = Integer.parseInt(input); //boolean is still true if it works
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                isInt = false; //changed to false if it doesn't
            }

            boolean isDouble = true; //same story
            try {
                double dbl = Double.parseDouble(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                isDouble = false;
            }

            if (isInt) {
                System.out.printf("%s is integer type%n", input);
            } else if (isDouble) {
                System.out.printf("%s is floating point type%n", input);
            } else if (input.length() == 1) { //this could be useless depending on your case
                System.out.printf("%s is character type%n", input);
            } else if ("true".equals(input.toLowerCase()) || "false".equals(input.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.printf("%s is boolean type%n", input);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s is string type%n", input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,
        boolean flag=false;
        while(!flag){
            try{
                str=sc.nextLine();
                n=Integer.parseInt(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("enter an no");
                str=sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this ok?

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        String x = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n The type of the variable is : "+x.getClass());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
subham@subham-SVE15125CNB:~/Desktop$ javac Test.java 
subham@subham-SVE15125CNB:~/Desktop$ java Test
hello

 The type of the variable is : java.lang.String
```

Answer (score -1):

But Zechariax wanted an answer with out using try catch

You can achieve this using NumberForamtter and ParsePosition.
Check out this solution

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;


    public class TypeChecker {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = "a"; // "1"
        NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
        numberFormatter.parse(temp, parsePosition);
        if(temp.length() == parsePosition.getIndex()) {
            System.out.println("It is a number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is a not number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really good, but I'm not that advanced (Sorry) and changed my mind of the whole Try catch it looks easier than this complicated code. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: I agree Zechariax. Try catch is a simple solution. But if you don't have that option you could use this at anytime.

Comment: Ok, also is there a way to use if(randomVar = (int)) {} or something like that? That would be the most useful.

Answer (score -2):

Try instanceof function with Integer instead of int.. each primitive also have a class

Comment: Can you give more description or a code? I don't know exactly how to use it, that will help thanks