# Check if input is of Primitive type in Java?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I have to check for each **input** and print out if it is an instance of a *primitive or referenced* type. But I am getting same output each time.

**Note: I do search SO, but no luck. [How can I check if an input is a integer or String, etc.. in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819889/how-can-i-check-if-an-input-is-a-integer-or-string-etc-in-java)**

### Code:

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for(int i=0; i<9; ++i){
        String input = br.readLine();
         showPremitive(input);//check for every input
    }     
}
public static void showPremitive(Object input){
    try{
            if (input instanceof Short)
                System.out.println("Primitive : short");
            else if(input instanceof Integer)
                System.out.println("Primitive : int");
            else if(input instanceof Long)
                System.out.println("Primitive : long");
            else if(input instanceof Float)
                System.out.println("Primitive : float");
            else if(input instanceof Double)
                System.out.println("Primitive : double");        
            else if(input instanceof Boolean)
                System.out.println("Primitive : bool");
            else if(input instanceof Character)
                System.out.println("Primitive : char");
            else if(input instanceof Byte)
                System.out.println("Primitive : byte");
            else  
                System.out.println("Reference : string");
         }  
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Exception occur = "+e);
    }
}
```

}

**Output:**

```
Reference : string
Reference : string
Reference : string
Reference : string
Reference : string
Reference : string
Reference : string
Reference : string
Reference : string
```

Comment: A `String` is a `String`.

Comment: You're always passing `showPremitive` a string (`input` specifically). So naturally it's going to say it's a string.

Comment: How are you supposed to identify conflicting input like `0`; is it a short, int, long, char, string or byte?

Comment: An instance of `Short` (etc) is not primitive: it is an instance of the wrapper type, so `input.getClass().isPrimitive()` won't ever return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I address your question, you appear to have a number of misconceptions about Java and `Scanner`.

1. The stuff you read from the input stream is characters or bytes.  Those characters or bytes can be interpreted as representing many things ... but it is a matter of interpretation.  Furthermore the same sequence of characters *could* mean different things ... depending on how you *choose* to interpret them; e.g. "12345" could easily be interpreted as a string, an integer or a floating point number.  And if you map that to Java types, then that could be `String`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` or `double` ... and many more besides.

   The point is ... you (the programmer) have to tell the parser (e.g. `Scanner`) what to expect.  You can't expect it to guess (correctly).
2. Assuming that you *had* managed to read as reference or (true) primitive types, you would not be able to assign them to the same variable.  `Integer` etcetera are NOT primitive types!
3. The `Scanner.readLine()` method reads and returns the rest of the current line as a String.  It makes no attempt to interpret it.  The Java type of the result is `String` ... and nothing else.

---

So how should you implement it.  Well here's a sketch of a crude version:

```
     String input = br.readLine();
     showPrimitive(input);  // Note spelling!

     public void showPrimitive(String input) {
         if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("true") ||
             input.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
             System.out.println("Primitive : boolean");
             return;
         }
         try {
             long num = Long.parseLong(input);
             if (num >= Byte.MIN_VALUE && 
                 num <= Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
                 System.out.println("Primitive : byte");
             } else if (num >= Short.MIN_VALUE &&
                        num <= Short.MAX_VALUE) {
                System.out.println("Primitive : short");
             } else if (num >= Integer.MIN_VALUE &&
                        num <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                System.out.println("Primitive : int");
             } else {
                System.out.println("Primitive : long");
             }
             return;
         } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
             // continue
         }
         // deal with floating point (c.f. above)
         // deal with char: input length == 1
         // anything else is a String.
     }
```

Note that the above entails using exceptions in a way that a lot of people would object to.  However, doing a better job is tricky ... if you are going to support all possible values of each of the primitive types.

But I would return to a point I made earlier.  If you look at the code above, it is making hard-wired choices about how to interpret the input.  But how do you know if you are making the right choices?  Answer: you have to *specify* how the input parsing should behave ... not rely on something else to give you the "right" answer by magic.

Comment: there is still a problem, if input is 0-9 , it may be char or byte?

Comment: Yea ... obviously.  Like I said, you need specify how that should be handled **in your requirements** ...

Answer (score 2):

You assign the input to a `String` variable. It's going to be a string.

```
String input = br.readLine();
//^^^ it's a string
//                  ^^^ readLine() returns String
```

---

What you are trying to achieve might not be possible using the method you have.

You're taking input using `java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()`.

See the [documentation for `BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

```
public String readLine()
                throws IOException
```

It returns a `String`, regardless of what the input actually contains.

For example, `"0"` is a string, even though it contains a number and *could* be converted to an `int`.

---

One possible method (if there's a built in or existing method, I don't know it) would be to repeatedly try to convert the input to each datatype you want to check for. Then print "string" if none match. For example:

```
String input = br.readLine();
try{
    int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    System.out.println("It's an int!");
}catch(Exception e){
    //well, guess not
    //do the same for all the other types
}
```

Here, I started with `int`. However, make sure you start with the most exclusive type. For example, an `int` can be casted to a `double`. Therefore, check for `int` *first*, or you could say it's a `double` when it can fit in an `int` (e.g. input is `5`, check that it's an integer before checking that it's a `double`).

Comment: what should I use for taking input?

Comment: That's why you have `catch`. If you enter a string, then `Integer.parseInt` will throw an exception, which you should catch. Then if there is an exception it means that the input isn't an integer.

Comment: I take this as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819889/how-can-i-check-if-an-input-is-a-integer-or-string-etc-in-java

Comment: It won't always work if he wants to print the type, for example 2.87 can be `double` and `float`

Comment: That's why I specified that he should start with the most exclusive type. I just gave an example for `int` vs `double`. I don't know enough about `double` vs `float` for a definitive answer on which to try first. Perhaps you could suggest a solution or simply edit.

Comment: @Arc676 So what is the better way?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean better? I only gave one solution.

Comment: @Arc676 yes and thank you but it still does not solve the whole problem. eg differentiation between int and long, float and doule etc.

Comment: You just have to keep trying to convert to different types. I just shortened it to one example in my post. Remember that you have to go from the most exclusive (i.e. `int` before `double`). Just keep nesting `try/catch` blocks for each type.

Comment: The only way to distinguish between `double` and `float` is to check `MAX_VALUE` (double will be bigger) or check how many bytes are used in the memory, which won't work in that case as the value is being cast from `String`.

Comment: @guy So essentially there's no way to tell if the input is `double` or `float`?

Comment: I don't have complete solution but if you give up on the type print and just print Primitive or Reference it will save you a lot of troubles.

Comment: @Arc676 No, there isn't (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

By checking the range of each data type. Please refer following formula for calculating the range of primitive data type.
-2^n-1 to +2^n-1

```
     int Byte=0;
     int Short=0;
     int Int=0;
     int Long=0;
     long temp=1;
     for(int i=1;i<=63;i++)
     {
        temp=temp*2;
     }
     long end=temp-1;
     long temp1=temp*2;
     temp=temp-temp1;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=sc.nextInt();
    
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {

        try
        {
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
            if(x>=-128 && x<=127)
            {
                Byte++;
            }
           if(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)
           {
               Short++;
           }
           if(x>=-2147483648 && x<=2147483647)
           {
               Int++;
           }
           if(x>=temp && x<=end)
           {
               Long++;
           }
           
           if(Byte>0 && Short>0 && Int>0 && Long>0)
           {
               System.out.println("* byte");
               System.out.println("* short");
               System.out.println("* int");
               System.out.println("* long");
               Byte=0;
               Short=0;
               Int=0;
               Long=0;
           }
           else if(Short>0 && Int>0 && Long>0)
           {
               System.out.println("* short");
               System.out.println("* int");
               System.out.println("* long"); 
               Short=0;
               Int=0;
               Long=0;
           }
           else if(Int>0 && Long>0)
           {
               System.out.println("* int");
               System.out.println("* long"); 
               Int=0;
               Long=0;
           }
           else if(Long>0)
           {
               System.out.println("* long"); 
               Long=0;
           }
           else
           {
               
           }
           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }

    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
2
11111111
11111111 can be fitted in:
* int
* long

1
1 can be fitted in:
* byte
* short
* int
* long
```