# How do I check if the user input is a of a char value?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a program that takes in user input to add characters to an array of a selected size. I want to check if what is entered is a char before adding it to the array. If it is not of char type, I want to print an error message and then ask the user to input a char again.

Here is my code and what I have tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CharArray
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of an array you want");

        char[] c = new char[kb.nextInt()];

        fillArray(kb, c);

        System.out.println("Original array:");
        printArray(c);

        sortArray(c);

        System.out.println("Sorted array:");
        printArray(c);


    }

    public static void fillArray(Scanner kb, char[] c)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a value [a,z]");
            if(kb.next().charAt(0) == ' ')
            {
                c[i] = kb.next().charAt(0);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(kb.next().charAt(0) + "is not in the interval. Please re-try:");
            }
            
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(char[] c)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void sortArray(char[] c)
    {
        int maxIndex;
        char temp;
        double count = 0;
       
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length-1; i++)
        {
            maxIndex = i;
                for(int j = maxIndex+1; j < c.length; j++)
                {
                    if (c[j]>c[maxIndex])
                    {
                        maxIndex = j;
                    }
                }
             
            temp = c[maxIndex];
            c[maxIndex] = c[i];
            c[i] = temp;
        }
    
    }
}
```

I am working in the fillArray method.

Comment: Your code pains me. Could you try `char[] c = kb.nextLine().toCharArray();` instead?

Comment: Where would I use that line?

Comment: To replace `char[] c = new char[kb.nextInt()];` and `fillArray`. Instead read a line of a text from the user. Any line of text from the user can only contain `char`s by definition.

Comment: First, you need to define what you mean by 'is a char'.  In some sense, everything you read from text input is made of chars.   Here's an example: if a user types ABCD on a line, do you want to interpret that as 4 chars, or reject it?

Comment: In my case, I want a char to be any single letter between a and z.

Comment: Here, take input as string , Then 1. Convert that to char is length is 1 . 2. add condition like if( input >='a' && input <='z')  . Similarly if you can add condition for A and Z.

Comment: Could you please show me? @SinghArun

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if an input is a integer or String, etc.. in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819889/how-can-i-check-if-an-input-is-a-integer-or-string-etc-in-java)